# RESTful POST request, If the record already exists on POST data, do we return 200 OK or 304 Not Modified?

Tags: rest, http

I have a POST request endpoint, where user repeatedly post the data. Before I insert the data to database, based on user request,I do check if the record already exists. 
- If record already exists, I return 200 OK with response body containing the table_id and status
- If record does not exists, I create new record and return 200 OK with response body containing table_id and status

Basically in both the cases, user get status 200. As user it might be confusing as one couldn't be able to distinguish whether its a new record or existing record.

I thought I would return 304 with response body and inform the consumer telling that This request is "Not Modified", in this way consumers would make a decision.

Is it a good practice or is there alternative approach in RESTful principals.

Comment: I come across this interesting topic here [http-response-code-for-post-when-resource-already-exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3825990/http-response-code-for-post-when-resource-already-exists?rq=1). Which one is desired to use 302 - FOUND, 303 - See Other, 304 - Not Modified. 302 make more sense to me :-)

Comment: The RFC [link](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-4.3.3) notes that 303 (See Other) should be used.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTTP response code for POST when resource already exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3825990/http-response-code-for-post-when-resource-already-exists)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`304` is intended to be used only for a *Conditional* `GET` response, to indicate that the requested content has not changed since the last time the client asked for it.  It is not appropriate for a `POST` response.

For a `POST` response, use `201` if a new record is created, otherwise use `200` or maybe `409` instead.

See the following for some helpful tips in designing REST APIs:

[Using HTTP 304 in response to POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20059297/using-http-304-in-response-to-post)

[HTTP response code for POST when resource already exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3825990/http-response-code-for-post-when-resource-already-exists)

[Creating an efficient REST API with HTTP](http://mark-kirby.co.uk/2013/creating-a-true-rest-api/)

[REST lesson learned: Avoid 204 responses](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2013/04/30/rest-lesson-learned-avoid-204-responses/)

Answer (score 2):

`304 Not Modified` is to be used when HTTP caching headers are in play, so this doesn't apply to your case.

I would use `422 Unprocessable Entity` that is for validation errors, when the request is well-formed but there are semantic errors.

And if the record did not previously exist, you should answer with `201 Created` (rather than `200 OK`) that is the standard response to a successful resource creation (following a POST creation request).