# Appropriate REST method/path/response for server operation

Tags: rest, api, restful-architecture, restful-url

I am looking for the best REST method/path to use in the following scenario:
There is a system with *users* and *projects* where each project has several *tasks* (task can only be associated with a single project), and each user can be assigned to any task.

The API I am willing to add is one that auto-assign a user to a task on a **specific** project, so basically the user asks the server to assign him some task.

I though about the following urls:

- `PATCH /project/{id}/tasks` - i.e the user asks the server to update the tasks list in the way the server thinks is best
- `PATCH /project/{id}/tasks/assign` - Have the specific operation part of the url

The reason I went with `PATCH` is because the task is only partially changed (each task has a `user` field which is basically what I want to update).

Another issue I am facing is what should be the response code in case there are no more "open" tasks left on the project? what would be the best way to signal to the user that he didn't get any new task?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

*Assigning* a task to a user is new `assignment` resource that contains `projectId`, `userId` and `taskId` (chosen automatically on the server side). Treating it that way allows to apply `GET`, `POST`, `DELETE` HTTP methods to manage a *particular* assignment only.

The resource URL(s) might (depending on your scenarios) be the following:

```
GET:  project/{id}/assignments/{userId}
POST: project/{id}/assignments/{userId}
```

Posting a new assignment should [return `201`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25896709/4207332) if there is a task found and an assignment created, and `200` if not.